# Show $\underbrace{{111\cdots}1}_{{\small{p-1} \ 1's}}$ is divisible by $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the shortest proof to show $\underbrace{{111\cdots}1}_{{\small{p-1} \ 1's}}$ is divisible by $p$

Comment: Try looking up Fermats little Theorem

Comment: As noted in comments to KV Raman's answer, this is false for $p=2,3,5$. (But true for all other $p$.)

Comment: In base $b,$ this will be false for any primes that divide either $b$ or $b-1.$

Comment: When I looked back my notes, I missed the point $p \geq 7$, and it is all my fault.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\underbrace{{111\cdots}1}_{{\small{p-1} \ 1's}} = \frac{10^{p-\small{1}}-1}{9} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

because by Fermats little theorem, since gcd$(10,p)=1, 10^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

NOTE: Assuming $p > 5$. The result is not true for $p=2, 3$ or $5$. In all the excitement to show, I missed important point.

For $p=2$ obviously $1$ is not divisible by $2$ - does not hold, and 
$p=3$, $11$ is not divisible by $3$ and finally for $p=5$ gcd$(5,10)=2$ and therefore not true as well ($1111$ is not divisible by $5$).

Comment: For completeness, consider the cases p=2,5 as well. (gcd(10, p) is not 1 in these cases)

Comment: How is $\gcd(10, p) = 1$? Are you assuming either $p \neq 2, 5$ or $p \ge 11$?

Comment: Ops. Posted same comment as Jan Grozny.

Comment: Also, the whole thing is false for $p=3$ due to that division by $9$.

Comment: @alex.jordan good catch

Comment: Thanks everyone for catching the ignorance so quickly.